# Optional Field in SharePoint Online Doesn't Allow Blanks

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, custom-field-types

First time coming over to the SharePoint area here. I'm experiencing an issue with our company's team site. We've set up custom managed metadata fields which use a closed term set. Changes cannot be made to the term set except by admins.

Using 'Classic SharePoint' (the old interface), we were able to leave these fields blank, but with the new SharePoint interface (or the underlying changes) we are no longer able to leave these fields blank. The columns are set up to be optional, so input should not be required.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

I've tried going back to the 'Classic SharePoint' site and can confirm that it is possible to set this field as blank with no error messages produced. This only occurs with the new interface, but if Microsoft is phasing the old interface out, then our site will have to work as intended with the new interface.

Is there any workaround for this, or is it something for Microsoft to fix?

Comment: I have tried it in my SPO site, I can leave it blank in new experience list (modern list). Do you use column formatting to customize this metadata column? Is there any customization in your site? Can you reproduce this issue in another list in another site?

Comment: There is no column formatting or customisation across the site...it should be fairly standard. I will try this one on another site to test though.

Comment: Setting up a test site in the same way, I am able to reproduce the issue, but I've realised that it's much more specific now. It is actually possible to leave the field blank when uploading a new document using the new interface. The problem only occurs when attempting to revert the tag to be blank once it has been set. Probably best to send this over to MS for them to look into it, though a temporary workaround would simply be to use the classic interface.